# Dropping an assumption in Hartshorne exercise 2.5.14 (a)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

In Hartshorne exercise 2.5.14, he defines the homogeneous coordinate ring for projective schemes over an affine scheme. Then he specializes to the case where $X$ is a connected normal closed subscheme of $\mathbb P _k ^r$ where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. In the first part of this exercise, we have to show that $S$, the homogeneous coordinate ring of $X$, is a domain. I did this by showing that $X$ is integral and using the usual argument, namely Nullstellensatz, to deduce that $S$ is a domain. However it seemed to me that assuming $k$ to be algebraically closed is maybe unnecessarily strong, since I did not use this assumption afterwards (I solved this exercise).

I tried to come up with a counterexample where $S$ is not a domain (when $k$ is not algebraically closed), but it seems that I am not used to dealing with these stuff.

Is there a counterexample?

Comment: Integral implies domain, no matter what base ring you are over - did you use $k$ algebraically closed to show that $S$ was integral? If not, you're good. If you did, could you please produce your proof so we can see where you used it and perhaps help you that way?

Comment: @KReiser I did not use it to show that $S$ is integral. I am confused because assuming $k$ is algebraically closed seems redundant (and I thought that the only possible place I may have used was there). Where would have I used it in this exercise?